# Аналог команды RUN в Docker

Tags: docker

Есть ли аналог команды RUN в DOCKER для запуска локального контейнера с аргументами, которые доступны для открытия портов? Допустим есть условно такая команда:

```
docker run \
--name dockername\
--env-file fileenv.conf \
--hostname mydomain.com \
-p 80:80 \
-p 443:443 \
-p 110:110 \
-v /directory/data/backup-mysql:/var/directory/directory    
username/reponame:stable
```

Эти аргументы судя по документации относятся к команде RUN, но у Меня есть локальный билд контейнера, который не хочу загружать на docker hub, как Мне его запустить с такими аргументами как выше? Облазив документацию, у Меня не получилось это сделать. Особенно интересует последняя строка `username/reponame:stable` которую обязательно требуется для RUN, но есть ли способ указать для RUN локальный контейнер? Я читал о том что одним из первых дел RUN ищет контейнер в docker hub, что в Моём случае совершенно не требуется.

Comment: `docker run` создаёт контейнер из образа и запускает его. Если у вас есть локальный образ, укажите его в последнем аргументе (вместо `username/reponame:stable`). Если же у вас есть уже созданный контейнер, то его запускает команда `docker start`. Что именно у вас есть - образ или контейнер?

Comment: Здравствуй @PakUula, у Меня есть готовый образ который надо запустить, но не могу понять как указать некоторые аргументы для открытия портов в мир, а именно команда `--service-ports`работает корректно, но с онлайн репозиториями(

Comment: Под каким именем виден локальный образ в `docker image ls`? Про `--service-ports` я вообще не понял - это функция из `docker compose`. Но пусть даже так - никто не в силах помешать вам указать в `docker-compose.yaml` локальный образ для сервиса.

Comment: @PakUula, проблема в том что запущенный контейнер открывает порты с `network_mode: host`, но не виден при обычном указании портов допустим ` ports:  - 80:80`. При этом если войти в работающий контейнер и допустим попробовать пропинговать сайт google.com, то он недоступен. То есть, порты контейнера недоступены изнутри и снаружи. Грубо говоря, докер не пробрасывает порты. Много разных инструкций перепробовал в интернете, но не помогло.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример `docker-compose.yaml`, с которым у вас есть проблемы. Причин может быть множество - отсутствие маршрутизации, поднятый файервол внутри контейнера, настройки `iptables` на хосте. Нужно попробовать ваш `docker-compose.yaml`, чтобы определиться с первоисточником

Comment: @PakUula, Вот примерно такой файл, он сокращён для упрощения, но никаких особых отличий нет, просто больше разделов и портов, но не более. `version: "3.3"
services:
  iredmail:
    image: iredmail/mariadb:stable
    container_name: containername
    hostname: hostnamedocker
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /iredmail/data/backup-mysql:/var/vmail/backup/mysql:rw`

Comment: @VarionDrakonov дополнения вносите в сам вопрос, комментарии не предназнечены для вставки блоков кода/конфигов и т.д. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите [edit] под ним.